# Can I register associated domain specifying a directory?

Tags: ios, xcode

There is no possibility to attach apple-app-site-association as it's specified in documentation:
**"smth.com/apple-app-site-association; smth.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association"**.
only through a front directory
**"smth.com/FrontDirectory/apple-app-site-association"**.

Is it possible to register associated domain with a directory this way **"app links:smth.com/FrontDirectory"** or are there any other workarounds?

Comment: No, the association file needs to be in the root or in .well-known in the root

Comment: @Paulw11 And if I register register domain/FrontDir as an associated domain, and it will be the root or it's just not possible?

Comment: Domain/FrontDir isn't a domain.  It is a domain and a path. The ASA file needs to be at the domain level.